How do I map a table-valued function (via DbFunctionBuilder) to an Entity result with Include() entities?

EF Core supports mapping a table-valued SQL FUNCTION to an existing Entity class type that's already associated with a TABLE. This is done with the DbFunctionBuilder type.
I have a FUNCTION in my MSSQL database that returns an entity, but it also returns other entities via INNER JOIN (and LEFT OUTER JOIN). However it's unclear how to configure EF Core to map those additional columns to those entities - just like how we can do that when using Include( e => ... )  to build an IQueryable<T>.


For example, consider your typical Customers, Orders, Products, and OrderItems database; though in this contrived scenario an OrderItem has two separate FKs to Products (expressed in EF by two navigation properties: PreferredProduct and BackupProduct).
So the original EFCore Linq-to-Entities IQueryable<OrderItem>, without using my UDF, would look like this:
List<OrderItems> items == await dbContext.OrderItems
    .Include( oi => oi.PreferredProduct )
    .Include( oi => oi.BackupProduct )
    .Include( oi => oi.Order )
        .ThenInclude( o => o.Customer )
    .Where( oi => oi.LineTotal >= 500 )
    .ToListAsync();

...but I want to do this:
List<OrderItems> items == await dbContext.GetLineItemsCosting500()
    .ToListAsync();


My DbContext has the GetLineItemsCosting500 configured like so:
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().ToTable("OrderItems");
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetLineItemsCosting500)));

public IQueryable<OrderItem> GetLineItemsCosting500()
{
    return this.FromExpression(() => GetLineItemsCosting500());
}

...and my UDF looks like this:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLineItemsCosting500)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
(
    /* The `SELECT  <cols>` part here was directly copy+pasted from the `SELECT <cols>` generated by EF's SQL when Include() was used; in this case, EF appended "1" and "2" to those columns to disambiguate PreferredProduct and BackupProduct. */
    SELECT
        oi.OrderItemId,
        oi.OrderId,
        oi.etc
        oi.PreferredProductId AS ProductId1,
        pp.Name               AS Name1,
        oi.BackupProductId    AS ProductId2,
        bp.Name               AS Name2,
        o.OrderStatus,
        o.CustomerId,
        c.Name                AS Name3
    FROM
        dbo.OrderItems AS oi
        INNER JOIN      dbo.Products  AS pp ON oi.PreferredProductId = pp.ProductId
        INNER JOIN      dbo.Products  AS bp ON oi.BackupProductId    = bp.ProductId
        INNER JOIN      dbo.Orders    AS o  ON oi.OrderId            = o.OrderId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c  ON oi.CustomerId         = c.CustomerId
    WHERE
        oi.LineTotal >= 500
)

...but presently, when I attempt to call the function from EF it disregards the columns from other tables so the OrderItem objects in the List<OrderItem> items all have their Order, PreferredProduct, and BackupProduct navigation-properties all null because EF doesn't know that those extra columns are available and should be mapped to those child/navigation entities (i.e. just-as-though I used Include()) - but I don't see any way to do this: I don't see any members of DbFunctionBuilder that act like Include().

When I use Include() on the Queryable<OrderItem> returned from FromExpression that causes EF to wrap the UDF call with an INNER JOIN on its own, instead of using the columns already in the UDF results table - which defeats the point of my FUNCTION returning those extra columns.

(I was able to get this to work by saving the generated SQL to a const string SLOW_QUERY and then used a custom command interceptor to check if the SqlCommand.CommandText matched SLOW_QUERY and if so, completely replaces the FROM clause with a call to my UDF - and this works great, but every time I make a change to any entity type then I need to manually update the SLOW_QUERY SQL, which is very tedious - so I'd rather get this working properly, somehow.)

I don't think you can do that. During translation of Include, EF adds joins and maps column indexes (not column names) to final mapping projection. In your case this mapping is unknown for translator. Does EF Core really builds slow SQL for such simple LINQ query?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv The query in my post is just an contrived example that demonstrates the mapping problem - the actual problem that caused me to use a UDF instead of using EF's SQL is more than just a slow query. But even if I wasn't using a UDF, I could be using RawSql() and the same problem applies - it seems really odd that EF doesn't have a way to do this...

Under hood, there  is really complex code which generates final mapper. Situation becomes more complicated if you include collections and single query is used for Eager Loading. During translation EF Core remembers many things for records deduplication. And I also don't think that EF Core has a way to do that via UDF.
